# QGIS Model Designer; save layer in geopackage with date

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, geopackage

I have used the model designer to make a model in QGIS.
The model takes data different shapefiles, and runs a few algorithms.

The result is different layers loaded in an new project.
I manually store these layers in a geopackage.

Example of tablename:
**week-37_high-detail-area**

I would like to add a step to the model, so it stores the output as a new table in an existing geopackage. I would like the model to store the layer to the geopackage with the number of the week in the tablename of the geopackage.
Is it possible to add some sort of expression section in the tablename?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have a model which extract raster pixels as points.

The output point layer is saved in the existing geopackage `/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/testdatabase.gpkg`

I set the output layer as the pre-calculated-value:

`format( 'ogr:dbname=%1 table=output_week_%2 (geom)', '/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/testdatabase.gpkg', week(now()))`

[image]

Comment: I have tried to replicate this but get the following error "OGR driver for '' not found (OGR error: )". Looks to me like it isn't picking which output format to use?